# Sharepoint public view not visible

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-on-prem

I created a public view over a list.
This list has about 52 views currently ( i know thats a lot ).
Its the heart of a ticketing system.

The problem when i use this list i dont see all public views when i want to set a view on pages where i include this list table. No errors gets reported
Is there something that i can do about this.

Or should i simply wait a day (perhaps something requires time to update)
Or is there a way to force something that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of SharePoint On-Premise are you using? There is a limit of 50 views within the List/LIbrary View Dropdown pre-SP2013. You can create more than 50, you will just need to know the URL of the view that is not visible within the list. If you are displaying the list as a web part/app within a web part page, only 50 views will display within the web part properties dropdown.

Comment: ok i solved it by a reboot, but i never knew of a 50 limit, so i mark you as answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings > Per-Location View Settings, in case if your newly created view is hidden for that particular location you could just add it to the "Views available at this location section" and try.

OR

If you are using a list view web part on a page, go to edit the web part > under the web part settings > "List Views" Be sure to select the View that is required under the selected view section.

Answer (score 0):

server reboot, solved it.
i don't think it should be solved like that, but apparently some things get triggered faster on restart.